# Error setting Win32 option for CUDA executable using CMake

Tags: cuda, cmake

I am building CUDA support into a CMake project that I have but I am getting a very strange error when trying to set the executable type to be WIN32.

Prior to using CUDA, I was adding my executable using the cmake command:

```
add_executable(${BINARY_NAME} WIN32 ${SOURCES})
```

which worked fine. Then, to add CUDA support I changed this line to be:

```
cuda_add_executable(${BINARY_NAME} WIN32 ${SOURCES})
```

which gives an error, as CMake incorrectly parses WIN32 as a source file. The specific error is:

```
Cannot find source file:

WIN32  

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx
```

When I tried to debug this, I looked in the CMake FindCUDA.cmake file where the error occurs and I can see that it fails to split WIN32 into a cmake option in the macro `CUDA_GET_SOURCES_AND_OPTIONS`. In this function it iterates over the arguments to cuda_add_executable and compares to the strings "WIN32", "MACOSX_BUNDLE", ..., that it expects as options but fails with the comparision of WIN32 because it is set automatically as CMake variable to 1/true.

I can sidestep this error but using `unset(WIN32)` before calling `cuda_add_executable` then resetting it afterwards but given that

1. There is nothing about this error online suggesting it's not a common problem
2. Using WIN32 is recommended on the [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCUDA.html)

Although I can avoid this error with a small hack, I'd rather not set myself up for a bigger failure in future as I assume that I've done something wrong in the setup despite the fact that CMake itself has set WIN32 as a variable. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Which CMake version? I'm looking at the `FindCUDA` module which ships with CMake 3.1, and that should definitely not suffer from this problem.

Comment: Hi @Angew I'm using CMake 2.8.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the `FindCUDA` module. I have CMake 2.8.12.1 installed, where this bug is present, as well as CMake 3.1, where it's already fixed. So one solution would be to upgrade to a CMake version where this is fixed.

If that is not an option for you, here's a workaround. All that specifying `WIN32` in the `add_executable` call really does is set the property `WIN32_EXECUTABLE` on the target to true. You can do this manually as well, instead of using `WIN32`:

```
cuda_add_executable(${BINARY_NAME} ${SOURCES})
set_property(TARGET ${BINARY_NAME} PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)
```